# Como alterar a posição do menu usando a função scrollTo?

Tags: javascript, html, rolamento

Estou fazendo um site e criei um menu com ancora que tem o efeito de *scroll* com Javascript. Até ai tudo bem, o único problema é que eu preciso que quando o Javascript entre em ação o conteúdo sempre fique embaixo do menu, mas eu não achei onde configurar isso.

Este é o código que vai diretamente na página:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        /** 
         * This part does the "fixed navigation after scroll" functionality
         * We use the jQuery function scroll() to recalculate our variables as the 
         * page is scrolled/
         */
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var window_top = $(window).scrollTop() + 12; // the "12" should equal the margin-top value for nav.stick
            var div_top = $('#nav-anchor').offset().top;
                if (window_top > div_top) {
                    $('header').addClass('stick');
                } else {
                    $('header').removeClass('stick');
                }
        });


        /**
         * This part causes smooth scrolling using scrollto.js
         * We target all a tags inside the nav, and apply the scrollto.js to it.
         */
        $("header a").click(function(evn){
            evn.preventDefault();
            $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash); 
        });



        /**
         * This part handles the highlighting functionality.
         * We use the scroll functionality again, some array creation and 
         * manipulation, class adding and class removing, and conditional testing
         */
        var aChildren = $("header li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
        var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
        for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
            var aChild = aChildren[i];
            var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
            aArray.push(ahref);
        } // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
            var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
            var docHeight = $(document).height();

            for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
                var theID = aArray[i];
                var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
                var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
                if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                    $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("header-active");
                } else {
                    $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("header-active");
                }
            }

            if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
                if (!$("header li:last-child a").hasClass("header-active")) {
                    var navActiveCurrent = $(".header-active").attr("href");
                    $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("header-active");
                    $("header li:last-child a").addClass("header-active");
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

E este é o código do Javascript:

```
$.scrollTo = $.fn.scrollTo = function(x, y, options){
if (!(this instanceof $)) return $.fn.scrollTo.apply($('html, body'), arguments);

options = $.extend({}, {
    gap: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    animation: {
        easing: 'swing',
        duration: 600,
        complete: $.noop,
        step: $.noop
    }
}, options);

return this.each(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: !isNaN(Number(x)) ? x : $(y).offset().left + options.gap.x,
        scrollTop: !isNaN(Number(y)) ? y : $(y).offset().top + options.gap.y
    }, options.animation);
});
};
```

[Aqui o link do site que estou fazendo](http://progdesenv.com.br/sites/twinshark/).
[E aqui o site do efeito que usei](http://callmenick.com/2013/04/22/single-page-site-with-smooth-scrolling-highlighted-link-and-fixed-navigation/).

Comment: O conteúdo já não está abaixo? Sua pergunta está pouco clara.

Comment: Deixa eu explicar quando o site carrega o contéudo esta realmente em baixo, mas quando vc clica em outra opção o conteúdo fica por trás do menu. O efeito está correto o problema é que eu preciso, que o menu fique sempre embaixo do conteúdo não importando o menu clicado

Answer (score 1):

Como o seu menu está no topo do site e não muda de tamanho (de acordo com o link do site que você disponibilizou), uma solução seria deixar ele com `position:absolute;` e criar uma div com `position:relative;` por trás dele, do mesmo tamanho, apenas para criar o espaçamento e deixar o restante do conteúdo alinhado.

Sendo assim não seria preciso nada desta parte em javascript que você tem hoje e deixaria o código mais limpo.